# How to turn a CSV file with several key value pairs a row into a dataframe with keys as columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to use panda to convert a csv.
I have *.csv file look like:

```
header1,value1,header2,value2,header3,value3,header4,value4  
header2,value2,header3,value3  
header1,value1,header2,value2  
header1,value1,header3,value3,header4,value4
```

I would like to have a new csv like:

```
header1,header2,header3,header4  
value1,value2,value3,value4  
,value2,value3,  
value1,value2,,  
value1,,value3,value4
```

the beginning of the code look like:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

# Read the file
df = pd.read_csv('in.csv')
df_data = df[1,9]

SOME CODE

df_data.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Thanks,

Comment: So what have you tried? `SOME CODE` is your attempt?

Comment: I try to separate the header from the value by using row_data = [row[1], row[3], row[5]] and row_header = [row[0], row[2], row[4]] in a for loop and write in the file but the header and the value are not align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load data without headers to keep it all in your dataframe:

```
df=pd.read_csv('foobar.txt', sep=',', header=None)
```

Then reshape it as a seriesbut keep the level 0 index to get row numbering from the original csv:

```
s = df.stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)

s
Out[92]: 
0     header1
0      value1
0     header2
0      value2
0     header3
0      value3
0     header4
0    value4  
1     header2
1      value2
...
```

Now concatenate odd and even fields of this series into a dataframe, add the header column to the index and unstack it:

```
pd.concat([s[::2], s[1::2]], axis=1).set_index(0, append=True).unstack(1)
Out[104]: 
        1                              
0 header1   header2   header3   header4
0  value1    value2    value3  value4  
1    None    value2  value3        None
2  value1  value2        None      None
3  value1      None    value3  value4
```